# How do you prefer between &cycle->read_events[i] and cycle->read_events+i

Tags: c, syntax

```
&cycle->read_events[i]


cycle->read_events+i
```

They are the same,how do you prefer one to the other?

Comment: It's a matter of coding standards and common language with your peers. Don't ask us, ask those who will be working with this code.

Comment: Screw all of y'all, I like the second one.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Assuming cycle->read_events is a pointer or array, they are identical within the language and will compile identically.

However, I prefer `&cycle->read_events[i]`, because someday you might decide to port to C++ and use a vector or other container class.  Such classes are more likely to have a `[]` operator than to implement `+` as "pointer arithmetic".  So this way makes it easier to change the data type without needing a recompile.

(Personally, I also find `&a[x]` to be more expressive of intent than `a+x`, but that is purely a matter of taste.)

Comment: I am firmly opposed to writing C code with "porting it to C++" in mind.

Answer (score 1):

According to *The Elements of C Programming Style*,

14.1 Use a[b] instead of *(a+b)

14.2 In general, use *a instead of a[0]

14.3 In general, use a+b instead of &a[b]

The rationales for each of these rules are roughly the same: it's shorter and usually clearer.